# SQL query to resolve transitive dependencies in database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[SQLFIddle link for this data.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0263a/22/5)

Suppose I have a table with following Structure:

```
create table rd(r1 number,r2 number, primary key (r1,r2));
```

Sample Data:

```
| R1 | R2 |
-----------
|  1 |  2 |
|  1 |  4 |
|  2 |  3 |
|  3 |  1 |
|  4 |  5 |
```

What it means is that R1 is related to R2 , bi-directionally. So if there is an entry in database for 1,3 there won't be an entry like 3,1.

According to above data:
1 is related to 2,4,3 directly. And 4 is related to 1 also . So via transitive dependency, 1 and 5 are also considered as related.

Expected result:

```
| R1 | R2 |
-----------
|  1 |  2 |
|  1 |  4 |
|  1 |  3 |
|  1 |  5 |
```

Can anyone write a SQL query for this?

Comment: What is the version of Oracle?

Comment: Oracle 11g , but database is not a primary constraint.

Answer (score 3):

As you are running Oracle 11g (and If it happens to be Release 2), as one of the methods, you can use recursive common table expression (also known as recursive sub-query factoring) [to get desired result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7fb60/16).

```
SQL> with rcte(r1, r2, lv, root) as(
  2    select r1
  3         , r2
  4         , 0 lv
  5         , r1
  6     from rd
  7    where r1 = 1
  8  
  9    union all
 10  
 11    select t.r1
 12         , t.r2
 13         , lv + 1
 14         , q.root
 15      from rd   t
 16      join rcte q
 17        on (t.r1 = q.r2)
 18  )
 19  search depth first by r1 set s
 20  cycle r1 set is_cycle to 'y' default 'n'
 21  
 22  select root
 23       , r2
 24    from rcte
 25  where is_cycle = 'n'
 26    and r2 <> root
 27  ;

      ROOT         R2
---------- ----------
         1          2
         1          3
         1          4
         1          5
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried on sqlfiddle , it works perfactly. 
But,
Is there a easy way ? I am not a DB expert and this terms are quite harder to understand for me.

Comment: This is **the** answer. Otherwise, choose a programming language and do the recursion on its side :)

Comment: @Raffaele: it can be written in a more compact way using `connect by`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/842b8/1  but it is essentially the same solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nice one!

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work as long as there is only one level of intermediate values in the table.

It works by expanding the table into a monodirectional one, and then combining that table with the results of joining it to itself.

```
WITH expanded AS
  (SELECT r1, r2 FROM rd
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r2 AS r1, r1 AS r2 FROM rd)
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT r1, r2 FROM expanded     -- direct relations
   UNION
   SELECT e1.r1 AS r1, e2.r2 AS r2 -- indirect relations
   FROM expanded e1
   INNER JOIN expanded e2
   ON e1.r2 = e2.r1                -- via transitive dependency
   AND e2.r2 <> e1.r1)
WHERE r1 = 1
ORDER BY r1, r2
```