# SQL query to remove transitive depencencies (instead of including)

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

Suppose I have a table with following Structure:

```
create table rd(r1 number,r2 number, primary key (r1,r2));
```

Sample Data:

```
| R1 | R2 |
-----------
|  1 |  2 |
|  1 |  4 |
|  1 |  3 |
|  1 |  5 |
|  4 |  5 |
```

What it means is that R2 depends on R1 , unidirectionally (R2 -> R1).

The above data means that 1 depends on 2,4,3 directly. And 1 depends on 5 by transitive dependencie, because 1 depends on 4 and 4 depends on 5. So via transitive dependency, 1 and 5 are related but I don't want to show this in my list.

Expected result:

```
| R1 | R2 |
-----------
|  1 |  2 |
|  1 |  4 |
|  1 |  3 |
|  4 |  5 |
```

Related links:

1. [SQL query to resolve transitive dependencies in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548988/sql-query-to-resolve-transitive-dependencies-in-database)
2. [transitive reduction algorithm: pseudocode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690953/transitive-reduction-algorithm-pseudocode)

Can anyone write a SQL query for this?

Comment: What want you to show in your list? Because the expected result and your data are the same.

Comment: Question fixed.

Comment: In the question please

Comment: *Can anyone write a SQL query for this* ? SO is not a coding writing service

Comment: Gurv and McNets, sorry, I am still learning how the stackoverflow works. Now I think the question is fixed.

Comment: Gurv, it will sure help to deliver a better quality result in my job, but at really I dont need to solve in SQL. I just think that would be nicer to solve in that way.